# usercreationform doesn't show any field

Tags: python, django

I'm new to django and as my first project I'm trying to make a website which has a sign up page. In order to do that I'm trying to use UserCreationForm method. I don't get any errors and everything is just fine. The only problem is that it doesn't show any username or password field in the web page. I mean in doesn't show any field that the UserCreationForm is supposed to show.

I searched a lot and I didn't find any related answer

```
from django.shortcuts import render, redirect
from django import forms
from django.contrib.auth.forms import UserCreationForm
from django.contrib import messages

def register(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = UserCreationForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            username = form.cleaned_data.get('username')

            messages.success(request, f'Account created for {username}!')
            return redirect('blog-home')
    else:       
        form = UserCreationForm()
    return render(request, 'users/register.html', {'from': form})
```

Comment: You've named your form in your context "from" not form

Comment: {'from': form} you have to change this to  {'form': form} and on your template you add it like this {{ form }}